# Spivak Calculus problem 9-17

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

This is problem 9-17 in Spivaks Calculus.

> 17. Let $0 \lt \beta \lt 1$. Prove that if $f$ satisfies $|f(x)| \geq |x|^\beta$ and $f(0) = 0$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

The answer book has the following solution:

$|f(h) / h| \geq |h|^{\beta - 1}$; since $\beta - 1 < 0$ the number $|h|^{\beta - 1}$ becomes large as $h$ approaches $0$ so $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h) / h$ does not exist.

My question is, the answer is proving that $f'(0)$ is not $0$. Would it be necessary to prove that $f'(0)$ is not equal to any other value?

Comment: The answer is not assuming $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: The answer consists in realizing that $f’(0)$ does not exist by definition

Comment: I've edited my question. The answer proves that $f'(0)$ is not $0$, but shouldn't it prove it for any other value?

Comment: @Jordi No matter how often you repeat this that is not what the solution says.

Comment: No, the answer does NOT prove "f'(0) is not 0".  The conclusion is that "so limh→0f(h)/h does not exist". Since the derivative IS that limit, f'(0) does not exist, not that it is not 0.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey Ok, now I understand.